# How can you run a personalisation test on two components with the same rule?

Tags: personalization

I have a Sitecore site on 8.2 in which the header comprises of three renderings, Logo, Navigation, and Quick Links.

I have set a personalisation on both the navigation (blue) and quick links (red) so that when a user enters the site on a specific page they are hidden.

See the two variations below:

[image: The two variations to test]

I want to test whether this has a positive effect on conversion, but I can't work out how to test it. I only want the test to run for users that have entered the site on the page that the rule mentioned above is using.

If I use a page test, all users will be tested not just the people that have landed on this page. This is not the test I want to run.

If I run a component test, there may be times when *either* red or blue are hidden, but I want it to be only the two variations below. Either all the navigation elements are shown or none.

The only way around this I can find is by adding a new component in which wraps the two navigation components (in green) and then personalising on this.

[image: Add a new component]

Does anyone know if there's a way I can run this test without having to build, deploy and reconfigure all the pages to use this new component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short; you can test *one* component and one component only.

To solve it, you would need to conduct the test either as you describe, a parent "meta" component or simply by testing 2 variations of your outer container (marked with black box) where the placeholders keys are being swapped.

I describe something similar in my answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/5902/73

In all cases, a redeploy will be required unfortunately.

If you want to restrict the test only to people who came in on a certain page, use the Rules Engine to trigger an event when people "land" on the page you want, and make the triggering of this even part of your conditions you set up with the test.